# How do I view a XAML control's default templates and styles without the Visual Studio designer?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp, windows-runtime

According to the Control template documentation on MSDN, the officially-supported way to view a Control's default templates and styles is with **Visual Studio's Designer** (well, technically the **Document Outline**, but that only works with the Designer turned on):

> A fast way to apply themes to your controls is to right-click on a control on the Microsoft Visual Studio **Document Outline** and select **Edit Theme** or **Edit Style** (depending on the control you are right-clicking on). You can then apply an existing theme by selecting **Apply Resource** or define a new one by selecting **Create Empty**.
>
> [...]
>
> The topics that document the styles and templates for XAML controls show you excerpts of the same starting XAML you'd see if you used the **Edit Theme** or **Edit Style** techniques explained previously. Each topic lists the names of the visual states, the theme resources used, and the full XAML for the style that contains the template. The topics can be useful guidance if you've already started modifying a template and want to see what the original template looked like, or to verify that your new template has all of the required named visual states.

However, developers may not have access to the Visual Studio Designer.

What *official*, guaranteed-up-to-date alternatives do I have to view the default templates and styles?

Thanks!

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the default styles of controls in **generic.xaml** file.

- If autocomplete/IntelliSense is working in your Visual Studio:

  1. Create a control that uses a built-in style, like `Style="{StaticResource ButtonRevealStyle}"`
  2. Hover the pointer over the `ButtonRevealStyle` and press **F12** or right-click and select the **Go to Definition** option to access the **generic.xaml**.
  3. In **generic.xaml**, you can search for a default style with a statement such as `Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button` in the search box to find the default style of `Button` controls.

  Note, please remove the statement `Style="{StaticResource ButtonRevealStyle}"` if you do not need the style `ButtonRevealStyle`.
- You can also find the file as part of the Windows SDK. It lives at **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.18362.0\Generic** (where **10.0.18362.0** is the version of the SDK, which you can replace with the version you are using).

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do this that does not rely on IntelliSense or Visual Studio? For example, is this file present in the https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml repo?

Comment: The link mentioned by you is related with WinUI library. If you want the generic.xaml file which contains XAML controls’ default templates and styles, you could find it in your local computer. The location of generic.xaml file  is **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.18362.0\Generic**. 10.0.18362.0 is the version of SDK, you could select the version of SDK that you are using.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was hoping for. I added the file location to the answer.