# Do the names of states in a VisualStateManager have meaning?

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-runtime

Are the names for states and `VisualStateGroup`s in `VisualStateManager` arbitrary, or do they have deeper meaning?

They seem similar to pseudo-classes in CSS, in some ways (`Button` has `CommonStates`: `Normal`, `PointerOver`, `Pressed`, and `Disabled`, whereas CSS has `:hover`, `:active`, and ways of targeting disabled controls). But they are also different—Checkbox has (it seems) [completely different states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/control-templates#specify-the-visual-behavior-of-a-control), like `Checked`, `Unchecked`, and `Indeterminate`.

As I develop my apps, how do I know which VisualStates are available? What happens if I use the wrong names?

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Do the names for states hold deeper meaning?

> Are the names for states and `VisualStateGroup`s in `VisualStateManager` arbitrary, or do they have deeper meaning?

The names for states and `VisualStateGroup`s *are* indeed arbitrary, but they *do* have a deeper meaning.

[VisualState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate?view=winrt-19041)s in [VisualStateManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.VisualStateManager?view=winrt-19041) are `[representations of] the visual appearance of a UI element when it is in a specific state`. They use [Storyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard?view=winrt-19041)s or Setters to represent arbitrary changes to a given Control (for example, make the background red). Control authors can call [VisualStateManager.GoToState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.gotostate?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_VisualStateManager_GoToState_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_System_String_System_Boolean_) within their codebehind to activate a named VisualState.

In this way, **VisualState names are arbitrary**: I could create a VisualState named `CitelaosGreatState` and activate it by calling `GoToState(this, "CitelaosGreatState")`. That's why there's such a variety of names—Buttons have the CommonStates you mentioned, while Checkboxes have completely different ones.

However, for practical purposes, **the VisualState names you choose are not arbitrary**.

If you are using a VisualStateManager to [modify the look & feel of a default control (by overriding the ControlTemplate)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/control-templates#specify-the-visual-behavior-of-a-control), **you almost certainly want to pick VisualState and VisualStateGroup names that correspond exactly to the names in the original ControlTemplate** (which you can find in the XAML designer or [in generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64932733/how-do-i-view-a-xaml-controls-default-templates-and-styles-without-the-visual-s)). This is a matter of functionality: the implementers of, say, `Button` chose an arbitrary name for the VisualState that appears when you hover a Button—`CommonStates` `PointerOver`. The logic in their codebehind that handles hovering a Button calls `GoToState(this, "PointerOver")` (or some equivalent). If you want to customize that appearance, you have to provide a VisualState with that name.

You can certainly *also* provide a cool state named `CitelaosGreatState`, or even `Hover`, but if the codebehind never calls `GoToState` with that same string, your state will never be activated, no matter the name.

Of course, that means for completely custom controls (where you control both the `VisualStateManager` *and* calls to `VisualStateManager.GoToState`), you can name your states whatever you want!

### How do I know which names to choose?

> As I develop my apps, how do I know which VisualStates are available?

- **Completely custom controls**: as above, if you are writing both the `VisualStateManager` and the calls to `VisualStateManager.GoToState`, name the VisualStates whatever you want! If you define a state named `State1`, you can activate it in codebehind with GoToState `State1`.
- **Custom templates for existing controls**: if you are retemplating an existing control (using `ControlTemplate`), you should choose names that match the existing states on that control. For example, Button defines `CommonStates`: `Hovered`, `PointerOver`, `Pressed`, and `Disabled`. Define those. States with other names will not ever be activated (since the codebehind written by the XAML team doesn't ever GoToState with that name). To know the existing states—

#### How do I know the existing VisualStates of a control?

1. Look up the default ControlTemplate (or `Style` with `TargetType` of your desired type) for your control (which, as mentioned earlier, you can find in the XAML designer or [in generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64932733/how-do-i-view-a-xaml-controls-default-templates-and-styles-without-the-visual-s)).
2. Use the names in the template's `VisualStateGroup`.

### Wrong name?

> What happens if I use the wrong names?

Since the names are arbitrary, "wrong name" is not the clearest question here. It's easier to look at two cases:

- You define a VisualState that codebehind never activates with `GoToState` (e.g. you added a state called `CitelaosGreatState` or `Hover` to your custom template for a Button): nothing awful happens, but your state will never be activated.
- You fail to define a VisualState that codebehind tries to activate (e.g. you added an incomplete VisualStateGroup for your custom Button template): the `GoToState` call has no effect.