# What's the recommend way to use Lightweight Styling in WinUI?

Tags: xaml, uwp, themes, winui-3, winui

XAML (UWP & WinUI) offers [lightweight styling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-styles#lightweight-styling), which lets developers override specific, named, brushes/resources for common controls. You can get a list of those  resources by looking at the control's default template ([accessible in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64932733/how-do-i-view-a-xaml-controls-default-templates-and-styles-without-the-visual-s)).

For example, offered on XAML's documentation:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackground" Color="Transparent"/>
                 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForeground" Color="MediumSlateBlue"/>
                 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderBrush" Color="MediumSlateBlue"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

However, this example doesn't answer a few of my questions:

- What should I do for *non*-light theme styles, like Dark mode & High Contrast?
- Do I have to define my own `SolidColorBrush`s? Can I use existing brushes, like the ones [documented in WinUI gallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/color#theme-brushes)?
- How do I override non-theme-specific resources? Like Thicknesses.

In short, **what's an end-to-end example of lightweight styling** that includes what I need to satisfy accessibility & use standard resources?

Comment: 1.[Specify theme dictionaries for both "Light" and "Dark" in addition to your "HighContrast" dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-theme-resources#guidelines-for-custom-theme-resources) if possible. 2. You can use predefined brushes such as in `Generic.xaml`. See [Lookup behavior for XAML resource references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-resource-dictionary#lookup-behavior-for-xaml-resource-references) for more information. 3. Set in XAML or Code.

Comment: It's better to [start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/get-started/start-here). And also check [sample repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/get-started/samples#samples-repositories). @citelao, have your questions been solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can also define "Dark", "HighContrast" if you need to. And you can also override (or make overrideable) other properties.

For example:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="ButtonBackground"
                    Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="ButtonForeground"
                    Color="GreenYellow" />
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="ButtonBorderBrush"
                    Color="GreenYellow" />
                <Thickness x:Key="ButtonBorderThemeThickness">10</Thickness>
                <x:String x:Key="MyButtonContent">DARK!</x:String>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="ButtonBackground"
                    Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="ButtonForeground"
                    Color="MediumSlateBlue" />
                <SolidColorBrush
                    x:Key="ButtonBorderBrush"
                    Color="MediumSlateBlue" />
                <Thickness x:Key="ButtonBorderThemeThickness">1</Thickness>
                <x:String x:Key="MyButtonContent">LIGHT!</x:String>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>

        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{ThemeResource MyButtonContent}" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```